# boost::variate_generator syntax error

Tags: c++, boost, random, compiler-errors

may I please seek some help with the issue I am having.
I have the typedef

```
 typedef boost::random::mt19937 my_rng;
 typedef boost::math::students_t my_st;
```

and then the following:

```
    my_rng rng(0) ;
    my_st  st(3);
    boost::random::variate_generator<my_rng&, my_st > noise(rng, st);
```

The compilation error that I get is (I am using visual studio 13 in windows 7) :

1>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59): error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 
'boost::math::students_t_distribution>'
1>          ....\test.cpp(183) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::random::variate_generator' being compiled
1>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'result_type'
1>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59): error C2602: 'boost::random::variate_generator::result_type' is not a member of a base class of 'boost::random::variate_generator'
1>          C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59) : see declaration of 'boost::random::variate_generator::result_type'
1>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/random/variate_generator.hpp(59): error C2868: 'boost::random::variate_generator::result_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name

Can someone please give me some pointers how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you list your includes? with `#include <boost/random.hpp>
` and `#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>
` I get no errors. MS v140 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`boost:math::students_t` does not satisfy the concept of a `Random Distribution`. Use `boost::random::student_t_distribution` instead.